# How to move one vector into another vector without copying

Tags: c++, copy, stdvector, move-semantics

I have a large `vector<object>` created inside a scope that I want to push into a vector residing outside that scope without copying it (since it is very large). Is there a way i can push vector v into vvec without doing a copy as I am doing currently?

```
std:vector<std::vector<object>> vvec;
{
    std::vector<object> v;
    v.emplace_back(object());
    vvec.push_back(v);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can `vvec.emplace_back()` a new empty vector then add to it with `vvec.back().emplace_back(object());`. It saves a move, but it may not be desirable from an exception safety point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `std::move` it

```
std::vector<std::vector<object>> vvec;
{
    std::vector<object> v;
    v.emplace_back(object());
    vvec.push_back(std::move(v));
}
```

If I mock a class as the following

```
struct object
{
    object() { std::cout << "default construct\n"; }
    object(object const&) { std::cout << "copy construct\n"; }
    object(object&&) { std::cout << "move construct\n"; }
};
```

then the above snippet of code now produces the output

```
default construct
move construct
```

therefore the inner copy was avoided by the move.

Comment: is it really that simple? :D

Comment: @Ddor There is an unbelievable amount of deep magic that was added to the language about 10 years ago to make it that easy.

Comment: @Ddor The "magic" user4581301 is referring to is related to the concepts of "move semantics" and [rvalue references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Rvalue_references), in case you want to read about it.

Comment: `std::move` is nothing but a *cast* to rvalue reference. If what you `std::move` is not movable (doesn't implement move constructor / move assignment operator), then a copy will still be performed.

Comment: @JesperJuhl that is true, but that is not the case with `std::vector`, which does implement move semantics